# Logging Data in Excel File using C#

Tags: c#, excel, logging

I have a requirement to log the range of data from multiple interfaces in the Excel file.

So, i can open an excel sheet and keep the data in the different worksheets of an excel sheet from multiple interfaces having an iteration period of somewhere 40ms to 100ms for different interfaces.

I have tried using the EPPlus library and able to push the data but its like I just collate the data and then push it in the Excel sheet. I am not finding any way where I can keep writing the data in multiple worksheets in parallel.

One approach I am trying to use with the InterOp but I am not sure if this work file where the very fast data is coming from multiple interfaces and needs to be filled in one or more worksheets.

Anyone can advice the best approach to do so?

Comment: This will not help but this is pure design for logging. The logging should be done in database. Some problems in excel if you want to search in the logs, you don't have any good solution, also xls max row number is 67k for xlsx is 1 milion, what are you going to do after this records are filled. If the main concern for logging in database is that the database will be filled with useless logs, you can delete the logs for execution with date of creation bigger than 30 days. Also I'm not sure that there is solution for your problem !

Comment: Actually I am thinking to have filters and Log levels to manage the log lines and I am also planning for the log rotation depending on the file size or something, so if that size is reached, application needs to make a similar excel again and start logging in that.

Comment: By using Excel, you are restricting yourself for future enhancements. `XML` is a better design decision, in my opinion, as it would give you more control and freedom to enhance. And `XML` can be imported into Excel (or even into a databse) whenever you want. It is a better tradeoff compared to a full fledged database.

Comment: XML is terribly verbose. It's a log, you don't want 80% overhead for file _structure_. **Plain UTF-8 encoded text**! To answer OP question: **buffering**. Even without Excel you seldom want to push log in real-time (especially if you log a lot). Keep logs in memory and write them every (let's say) second. Just don't forget to handle...unhandled exceptions (to flush your logs).

Comment: yeah, Plain text values are good to go as XML needs proper alignment with the fields and values and pushing that to excel will be cumbersome thereafter if the size will become big. Buffering is one way but there the issue lies in how many buffers and the parallel working of those buffers as if one buffer is populating the excel the another buffer should keep accumulating the data and there needs a sync also as all the data will be time bound e.e. 500 values sticks to one timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You actually describe two kinds of functionality here - logging and reporting.

Excel file is by no means a realtime data storage. It's suitable for reporting, but not for logging.

I would suggest accumulating data somewhere else, for example in a relational database or just in csv files, depending on your reliability and scalability needs, and aggregate the excel files for closed time periods, for example: dayly, hourly, every minute.

If you absolutely need to add many items to different excel sheet at runtime, you can use Microsoft OleDb driver:

```
        const string connectionString =
             @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;Data Source=C:\source\MyExcel.xlsx;";
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            foreach (var sheet in new[] { "sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3" })
            {
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" + sheet + "] (id INT, datecol DATE );";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception) // TODO: find better way to determine existing sheet
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Can't create {0}", sheet);
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        var datecol = DateTime.Now;
                        var id =  i;
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + sheet + "](id, datecol) VALUES(@id,@datecol);";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@datecol", OleDbType.Date).Value = datecol;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: i agree on that point that CSV should be the best way but the client requirement needs Real Time data storage in excel. So, the best way I am looking is like accumulating the data in different buffers and push those buffers in the existing excel one by one. It will be like a buffer pool. I am not sure if this approach will work or not.